# How to get dependencies for a patched .jar library in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

We are using a patched version of Selenium, and we'd like to use our patched jar as a file dependency while getting all the dependencies of Selenium from a Maven repo without specifying them manually. Is this possible?

Today we add the patched selenium jar together with it's dependencies as a dependency to our project using a fileTree dependency, but this is not ideal since it's ugly and also sometimes seem to mess up Gradle's conflict resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I'd recommend to publish the patched Jar to your corporate Maven or Ivy repository (Artifactory, Nexus, etc.), along with a suitable dependency descriptor. Of course there are other solutions, like the following:

```
apply plugin: "java"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    rawCompile
}

dependencies {
    rawCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
    compile configurations.rawCompile.filter { it.name != "junit-4.11.jar" }, files("lib/junit-4.11-patched.jar")
}

task debug << {
    println "original dependencies: $configurations.rawCompile.files \n"
    println "changed dependencies: $configurations.compile.files"
}
```

A potential problem with this and similar solutions is that file dependencies (which is what you end up with on `compile`) don't participate in conflict resolution.

Comment: Will conflict resolution work properly for libraries that are in both `compile` and `rawCompile` above?

Comment: `configurations.rawCompile.filter { ... }` returns a `FileCollection`, which won't take part in any further conflict resolution.