# Change package in 3d-party jar using Gradle

Tags: java, android, spring, jar, gradle

I want to repackage `spring-context.jar` (my project depends on it) before assembling it into Android apk. What needs to be done:

1. Extract jar
2. Patch all invocations of java.beans package to another package
3. Compress it again into jar

I need to replace all references to java.beans package because this package is not fully implemented on Android, so that I can't launch plain Spring there (I'm going to use some open-source implementation like Openbeans instead of java.beans).

Is there some libraries or tools that could patch .class files like above?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it be *far* better to replace `spring-context.jar` with something that is known to actually work on Android?

Comment: No, because application I'm trying to port to Android is already with Spring and has a lot of dependencies to Spring.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384442/how-to-get-dependencies-for-a-patched-jar-library-in-gradle